# Horizontally swap/flip (Mirror Image) the contents of the entire device screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need a simple Android  app that can reverse the screen; horizontally swap/flip (Mirror Image) the contents of the entire device screen, left to right, including text, video, everything. When this app is started, I need a visible "button" located maybe at the top left or maybe a user selectable location (I'm open to suggestions for the on/off event), that when tapped, will instantly reverse the entire screen and, if tapped again, will put the device screen back to normal view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your scaffold with `Transform` widget and have tapped boolean to toggle

```
Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
              ..rotateX( tapped ?  pi : 0),
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: Scaffold(),
          ),
```

you can apply animation of you want also
also your mirror direction depends on rotateX or rotateY function to call

Answer (score 0):

Did this work for you?

I found a solution, using two phones/tablets (one of them has to be an Android):

https://xdaforums.com/t/q-app-that-mirrors-the-screen-to-use-it-as-a-hud.778845/post-89390441

Basically, i screen cast to a website, open that website on another phone and apply a CSS snippet to flip this website horizontally, giving the mirror effect (i suppose you could flip it vertically as well).

Comment: I think OP wanted to build an app that implements this feature, given this is part of the Mobile Development Collective.